# Pressure/Voltage analogy

Tags: voltage, current, pressure

Imagine a hydrocarbon being pumped through a flow line

Now imagine if a valve downstream of the pumps was shut and then you were pumping against pressure !

Ok, this will cos a rupture of your flowlines, obviously

My question is, if voltage can be likened to pressure

And current to the actual hydrocarbon

And the closed valve = resistance

Can we ever have a similar occurrence in electronics/electricals ?

I am thinking no because in the hydrocarbon case the pressure differential (equivalent of EMF) is between the pumps and the closed valve, so you still have flow between those paths

But in the electrical world, the Potential difference( equivalent to pressure differential) is between the electrode with more electrons and the one without, and since we have an infinitely large resistance between the two electrodes, there is practically no differential anymore so current does not flow

Also, the mass of an electron is too small to cause a breakage or rupture of the wires

Am I right or wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Essentially your question is whether a resistor can 'give-in' to pressure. The answer depends on what material the resistor is made of. If it is a dielectric (silicon say) then yes, at high enough pressure it will undergo dielectric breakdown. Metals are a different story.

Comment: Nice try but no similarity in transfer functions.   It is more like a transmission line with impedance mismatching and wave effects with closed valve like a short circuit with current return like pressure build up and source impedance of pump with and leakage hydrocarbon l, but still not a great model. You need the equations and values for mass thus momentum , pipeline length , viscosity, temperature, eddy current losses etc

Comment: An autotransformer or coil with points as used on older cars may be a relevant example - current flow stops in low v circuit and causes energy & spark in high v...

Comment: Why specifically hydrocarbons?  It seems what your analogy is for liquids, but hydrocarbons can be gas, liquid, or solid.  I don't understand what are trying to say by going out of your way to mention hydrocarbons.  This makes no sense.

Comment: Oh my god.. This has now hit the hot network list.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I am sorry for the ambiguity, I meant an actual 3-phase hydrocarbon (Oil, Gas and water)

Comment: @IshankJuneja That makes sense

Answer (score 4):

Like most analogies, there are some differences, but, yes,
closing a valve CAN cause a buildup of voltage; that's how
an automobile spark coil operates.   The trick is sometimes known
as 'flyback', and is an important way to produce high voltages.

So, the difference starts with hydraulic 'closing a valve' becoming
electrical 'opening a switch'.   Both mean that one impedes the flow.   It continues
with 'pump causing pressure to rise' being replaced with
'inductive kick' which is similar to using a mass of
moving water to lift some of that water to a high elevation.
That difference is because most electrical current sources do not
ignore back-voltage, a battery simply ceases to supply
current when you turn a flashlight off (but adding a magnetizable
element, an inductor, changes that equation).

The equations that describe an inductor (aka coil or electromagnet)
are equivalent to giving a momentum term to the slow-moving current of
nearly-massless electrons.

And finally, the 'breakage of a pipe' becomes the breakage that
occurs with high voltage, the breakdown of insulation (and 
across the insulating electrode gap of a spark plug, fires the internal
combustion that makes your car go).

Answer (score 2):

You have to look into more detail.

An ideal voltage source delivers constant voltage, regardless of the current it has to provide. An equivalent water pump has to deliver constant pressure, regardless of the water flow.(In reality, if you pull too much current / water, the voltage / pressure drops)

Now, if you attach long wires / long pipes with an open switch / a closed valve, the voltage / pressure is constant over the entire length.

If you replace the switch by a resistor / open the valve a little, the voltage  / pressure will still be the same over the entire length, and will drop just inside the resistor / valve.

If you use a resistor with low value / open the valve wide, the resistance over the wire / pipe will become noticeable, and Voltage / pressure will fall a little over the wire / pipe.

Now about your effect:

If a high  water flow is suddenly stopped, the inertia of the moving water will cause a high pressure peak, which depends on how much water flows, and how fast it was interrupted. This peak is much higher than what the pump can deliver, and can cause the pipes to burst.

The same is true for an electric circuit, though it's not the inertia of electrons, but the magnetic field which builds up around each current. If the current is suddenly interrupted, the field tries to maintain the current, and if that's not possible, the voltage increases way above the source voltage. How much, depends on the current flow, how sudden the current is interrupted, and the inductance of the setup. (Iron near the wires increases inductance a lot). This can destroy electronics, but can also be used to generate high voltage. As written by others,  the ignition spark in a motor is created this way.